# Help me in finding all possible cases for Facebook Posts' privacy options

Tags: facebook

For a little application of mine,
I am looking for all the possible cases for Facebook Posts' privacy options,
so that I can classify a particular Video update in the corresponding category.

I am able to find the following until now:

```
NO_PRIVACY            :: Visible to everyone, regardless of Privacy Settings
SELF                  :: Set to Privacy: Only Me = SELF
EVERYONE              :: Set to Privacy: Everyone = EVERYONE
FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS    :: Set to Privacy: Friends of Friends = FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS + EVERYONE + CUSTOM::FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS
NETWORKS_FRIENDS      :: Set to Privacy: Networks and Friends = EVERYONE + NETWORKS_FRIENDS
ALL_FRIENDS           :: Set to Privacy: Friends Only = EVERYONE + ALL_FRIENDS + FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS + NETWORKS_FRIENDS + CUSTOM::ALL_FRIENDS + CUSTOM::FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS
ONLY_NETWORKS         :: Set to Privacy: All Networks, No Friends = EVERYONE + NETWORK_FRIENDS + DESCRIPTION::NETWORKS
NETWORK FOR           :: Set to Privacy: A particular Network
SOME_FRIENDS FOR      :: Set to Privacy: Visible to particular friend
```

Can you add a case I've missed to these privacy settings, or maybe I've arranged some privacy wrongly??

Additionally, though not required, can some one help me list all the Facebook Connections, which does possess a stream of their own, e.g. photos, videos, links, events, etc. Each of them can have a stream of their own. I am looking for all such possible values, where the updates in a user's account can be divided into smaller components/streams.. The streams can be very obvious like Statuses, or something unusual like relationships...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy options i dont think you have left anyone.

And list of connections is very long so consider looking here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

How you were able to find them? they are clearly stated in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). Am I missing the question here?

Comment: What I am trying to ask here is that I am making a list of privacy modes a user can select. Now, we are limiting the privacy based on third person. So, if a user selects Everyone, we only need to extract data where the privacy is such that Everyone is able to see this data. So, if he selects Friends, all the data which his friends can see, we provide him with this data (this includes privacy modes such as friends of friends, friends and networks etc).

Comment: hmm, Still not sure what kind of functionality you are trying to achieve..but you are aware that the privacy setting only works on your own wall posts, right?